# How to git merge code between two different repositories?

Tags: git

I have got `2 git repos` but has the **same code base** with some differences according to environment

**Scenario**

```
GIT-REPO-A -  DEV environment
GIT-REPO-B -  QA environment   (same code-base as that of Repo-A)
```

1. How can I generate the `git-diff` between `2 different repos` though the code base is same ?
2. Is there any way to merge the code from `Repo-A` to `Repo-B`?

Kindly let me know whether this is doable

Comment: A local repository only has a single remote by default (namely `origin`), but you can add additional remotes (git repo servers or git repo folders). Then you can fetch from those additional repos and use git diff and git merge on their remote branches. e.g. `git remote add qa ../qa` `git fetch qa` `git diff origin/master qa/master` `git merge qa/master`. Have a look at `git remote --help` for more info.